# height vs position vs padding in KeyboardAvoidingView "behavior"

Tags: android, ios, react-native

There is a "behavior" property in KeyboardAvoidingView, e.g.:

```
import { KeyboardAvoidingView } from 'react-native';

<KeyboardAvoidingView style={styles.container} behavior="padding" enabled>
    ... your UI ...
</KeyboardAvoidingView>
```

It can be picked as one of three choices: `'height'`, `'position'`, or `'padding'`.  The difference is not explained [in the documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/keyboardavoidingview.html#behavior).  All it says is that it's not required to set the property, and has a note:

> *Note: Android and iOS both interact with this prop differently. Android may behave better when given no behavior prop at all, whereas iOS is the opposite.*

What effect are these settings supposed to have?

Comment: I don't have anything set up to experiment with it on hand...but from a quick skim of a few pages that mention it, it seems to be regarding how the `keyboardVerticalOffset` number is interpreted.  *(also, the attributes aren't listed in alphabetical order, so the fact that `behavior` is right after that property likely has meaning)*.  You might try just changing the parameter for a simple layout and tweaking that number to see what the effect is.

Comment: Their documentation is really miserable

Answer (score 39, accepted):

I agree that the lack of documentation here is frustrating. If you dig into the source code for `KeyboardAvoidingView`, you will find a switch around the `behavior`: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/92073d4a71d50a1ed80cf9cb063a6144fcc8cf19/Libraries/Components/Keyboard/KeyboardAvoidingView.js#L157

It looks like the following is happening:

> `height`

A `<View>` is returned with styling that attempts to set a static height to the view that is either the screen height, or the screen height minus the keyboard when the keyboard is present.

> `position`

A nested `<View>` is returned, where the outer View has your styles applied, and the inner View has a `bottom` style applied that attempts to match the keyboard height when the keyboard is present.

> `padding`

A single `<View>` is returned where a `paddingBottom` style is applied to the height of the keyboard if the keyboard is present.

---

Given the arbitrary options available, it looks like when using the `KeyboardAvoidingView` you should exercise trial and error, and check both devices for your desired outcome. In theory all three options should work, but as the docs say there is some nuance between device types.

In my opinion, this component should be scrapped though, in favour of helper functions that would return keyboard heights over time, so you could apply your own style ideas directly based on keyboard visibility.

Answer (score 11):

Allow me to go through these attributes for the prop behavior one by one.

I am considering the `<TextInput>` object for which our keyboard gets called.

1. **"padding"**: The `<TextInput>` component goes to a higher position once the keyboard pops up. It is advised to use padding when there are not many components on the screen otherwise the layout might break where the `<TextInput>` component may overlap with the components above it *(Note that the components above it would also be moved up, but in order to adjust the Views there might be an overlap)*.
   Also note that both the `<TextInput>` and the components may get overlapped.
2. **"position"**: The entire View containing `<TextInput>` would be moved up and there is a chance that some of the components above may not be available or visible on the top of the screen i.e. they would be cut off from the top where top of the screen is the upper bound.
3. **"height"**: Generally used with `keyboardVerticalOffset`. It is used to resize the View of the screen once the keyboard pops up. It might as well lead to overlapping in an attempt to resize the screen. Here, the `<TextInput>` would be overlapping above the component above it in case of an overlap.

**Note: when we are wrapping our screen inside a ScrollView make sure to wrap the ScrollView with <`KeyboardAvoidingView style={{flex:1}} ...>` where flex:1 should be used to occupy the entire component as ScrollView is wrapping the Component**

Answer (score -6):

For the ios, you can use `padding` to the `behavior` props.
Like this

```
<KeyboardAvoidingView behavior="padding" style={{flex: 1}}>
...
</KeyboardAvoidingView>
```

For the Android, it's better without `behavior` props.

Comment: This answer is outdated. Setting behavior is recommended on both iOS and Android based on latest React Native documentation.